# What is the benefit of downvoting whereat the reputation is reduced?

Tags: discussion

If I downvote an answer or a question my reputation will be reduced by 1. In the question [*Should I downvote spam?*](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/838/should-i-downvote-spam) the message is bold => **downvote to help "normal" users**.

What is the benefit of downvoting?

Today I downvoted a spam answer in the question: [Check if next char is {](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33455/check-if-next-char-is)

Comment: Could you rephrase that. I have difficulties following you. What do you mean with "In the question Should I downvote spam? the message is bold => downvote to help "normal" users."? This is not discussed in that question. Are you now talking about the benefit of downvoting for normal posts or spam posts?

Comment: Also note that down-votes on *questions* are now free and do not reduce your reputation.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Question down-votes are "free"? How new is this?

Comment: @Werner: It has been so for a while, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason down-votes exists is similar to the reason up-votes exists. The total sum of votes should indicate how good an answer is perceived by the community. Good posts should be up-voted, not-good posts should not receive votes and really bad or incorrect posts should be down-voted.

You need to pay 1 rep for a down-vote on a question so that you won't down-vote just for fun and take it serious. If the post is deleted afterwards you can get your reputation back by recalculating it (go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation#bottom and press the button there). If the post is improved by an edit you can remove the down-vote and get the reputation back as well.

Spam posts should be simply flagged as spam using the 'flag' link below it. You can down-vote it as well, but this is not required.

Comment: Your answer explains my questions.

Comment: IIRC flagging as spam automatically downvotes.

Comment: @Caramdir: Yes, right, I forgot that. But this vote comes from Community, not from you.